# Difference between syncExec() and asyncExec() of Display class

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I'm working on a plugin project in which I'm using Eclipse background processing.
What's the difference between the [syncExec()](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FDisplay.html&anchor=syncExec(java.lang.Runnable)) and [asyncExec()](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FDisplay.html&anchor=asyncExec(java.lang.Runnable)) methods of the [Display](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FDisplay.html) class? In which situations are they applicable? Any example could be helpful.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

from [Q: Why do I get the error "org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access"?](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#uithread)

> To allow background threads to perform operations on objects belonging to the UI-thread, the methods syncExec(Runnable runnable) and asyncExec(Runnable runnable) of Display are used. These are the only methods in SWT that can be called from any thread. They allow a runnable to be executed by the UI-thread, either synchronously, causing the background thread to wait for the runnable to finish, or asynchronously allowing the background thread to continue execution without waiting for the result. A runnable that is executed using syncExec() most closely matches the equivalent direct call to the UI operation because a Java method call always waits for the result before proceeding, just like syncExec().

Answer (score 6):

Adding to Tom Seidel's answer, here are examples of situations where you might want to use one or the other:

- Use `asyncExec` when you want to update something in the UI without caring about the results. For example updating a label or a progress bar.
- Use `syncExec` where the code following that method call needs to be sure that the UI is in a consistent state, or needs some data from the UI. For example getting some data from a user dialog. Or you update a widget and before doing anything else (e.g. another UI update) you want to know that the widget update has completed.

Answer (score 1):

SWT implements single threaded UI model. In this model, only the UI-thread can invoke UI operations. If you try and access an SWT object from outside the UI-thread, you get the exception "org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access". So to allow other threads to perform operations on objects belonging to the UI-thread, SWT provides syncExec and asyncExec methods.

This [link](http://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.in/2017/04/swt-syncexec-vs-asyncexec.html) may help you with an example